# flicker when destroyComponents() and redraw c++builder

Tags: windows, c++builder

In c++Builder, I have a form with a TPageControl, which has several TTabSheet with ScrollBox alClient inside. In each of these ScrollBox are dynamically drawn several TStringGrid and their information is filled according to a binary file read by an OpenDialog.

For dynamic create the components, I write the function

```
    void __fastcall TForm1::DynamicDraw()
```

which takes the file and draw on all TTabSheet (with dependencies).

The problem arise because the user can delete/add TStringGrid generating dependency problems in all other TTabSheet.

To solve this I decided to call the function

```
    ScrollBox->DestroyComponents();
    DynamicDraw();
```

for each TTabsheet. However this creates a "flicker" in the current tab even if DoubleBuffered activated.

Any thought or information to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the ScrollBox `WM_SETREDRAW` messages to temporary disable screen painting while you are making updates:

```
SendMessage(ScrollBox->Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0);
try {
    ScrollBox->DestroyComponents();
    DynamicDraw();
}
__finally {
    SendMessage(ScrollBox->Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE, 0);
    ScrollBox->Update();
}
```

Comment: It Works!
However, for Dynamicall created TstringGrid, i have to iterate over the ScrollBox->Component[i] and call Invalitade() for every new grid in the ScollBox.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Repaint()`.  `Update()` merely processes pending paint messages, but `Repaint()` calls `Invalidate()` and `Update()` to force a repaint.